# Import servlet in JSP Index => Null parameter

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, jsp, servlets

I'm currently working on a school project. We have to do a small market website in Java.

I've a small problem. I have an Index.jsp where i want to include a servlet (RandomArticle.jsp). This servlet have a .jsp and a .java and just shuffle a collection and return names.

When I display index.jsp, the html of RandomArticle.jsp is well displayed (so the include is correct) but the returned name are "null".

Here is some code:
Index.jsp (in WebContent of eclipse)

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Market</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <header>
            <h1>market 2013</h1> 
            <h2>Bievenue </h2>
        </header>
        <nav>
        <% String include = "/WEB-INF/RandomArticle.jsp"; %>
        <jsp:include page='<%=include%>' />
        </nav>
    </body>
</html>
```

RandomArticle.jsp (in WEB-INF):

```
<h1>Liste des produits EpiMarket</h1>
<%
String productName1 = (String) request.getAttribute("productName1");
String productName2 = (String) request.getAttribute("productName2");
String productName3 = (String) request.getAttribute("productName3");
%>
<p>Acheter <% out.println(productName1); %></p>
<p>Acheter <% out.println(productName2); %></p>
<p>Acheter <% out.println(productName3); %></p>
```

Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>Market</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Test</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>fr.market.servlets.Test</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Test</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/test</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>RandomArticle</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>fr.market.servlets.RandomArticle</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
</web-app>
```

and RandomARticle.java

```
public class RandomArticle extends HttpServlet {

    private ArrayList<Object> allProducts;

    public String getProductName(int index){
                return (((AbstractProduct) allProducts.get(index)).getName());
           } 

    public void doGet( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response ) throws ServletException, IOException{
         ADAO<AbstractProduct>  dao = new DAOProduit();
         allProducts = ((DAOProduit) dao).getAll();


         Collections.shuffle(allProducts);
         request.setAttribute("productName1", getProductName(0));
         request.setAttribute("productName2", getProductName(1));
         request.setAttribute("productName3", getProductName(2));
         this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher( "/WEB-INF/RandomArticle.jsp" ).forward( request, response );
     }
}
```

I think that the .java is never called, but I don't understand why.
Thanks for your time.

Gilles

Comment: What HTTP request are you making that makes you think that the servlet isn't be used?

Comment: If the address bar contains /index.jsp, then you're indeed invoking the JSP directly, and there is no reasong for the servlet to be executed. You need to use the URL of the servlet for this servlet to be executed. But since you didn't map the servlet to any URL in your web.xml, I don't see how it could be executed.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. @JBNizet, I don't want to map the servlet, i want to have the servlet inside my index.jsp. Not with a /RandomArticle after the url.

SotiriosDelimanolis I Thinks it's the .java that is not used because when I map my servlet, it works perfectly (if, for example i try it with MyUrl/RandomArticle)

Comment: To be included, the servlet needs to have a URL. You're not including the RandomArticle servlet but the RandomArticle.jsp JSP.

Comment: If I map, the servlet will work well in the url I mapped it, but I need to have the servlet inside my index.jsp (and all the parameters return null). I need the servlet to be like a part of the page, you see ? Excuse me, i'm not well-trained with Java and Jsp ^^

Comment: Servlets don't sit inside JSPs.  The usual pattern for this is to call a servlet, which uses a JSP to display its output.

Comment: I you are saying that I have to map the servlet ? There is no other way to "cut" my index.jsp into some other jsp in order to keep my code clean and re-usable ? :/

Comment: There's nothing in Index.jsp that refers to the RandomArticle class. You can include its results if you correctly refer to its mapped URI in your jsp:include tag.